# Calculate higher unit first then lower only showing showing whole numbers

Tags: sql-server

| Available | qty/pallet | qty/box |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4800 | 2400 | 120 |
| 1500 | 1000 | 100 |
| 300 | 2000 | 100 |

I am trying to add two additional columns, pallet and boxes. It would basically calculate the Available qty divided by either qty/pallet and qty/box. Pallet would be calculated first and if it results in a fractional number, it would only capture the whole number and carry over the remainder for the qty/box to be calculated further. The result should only be showing whole numbers (results shouldn't be rounded).

My goal would be something like the below

| Available | qty/pallet | qty/box | pallets | boxes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4800 | 2400 | 120 | 2 | 0 |
| 1500 | 1000 | 100 | 1 | 5 |
| 300 | 2000 | 100 | 0 | 3 |

I am thinking of something like a case statement

I am using Windows SQL Server 2016.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Something like floor(available/qty_pallet) as pallets, ceiling(mod(available, qty_pallet)/qty_box) as boxes could do the trick . Where mod() is whatever modulus function your DBMS supports. And floor() is whatever round down to nearest integer it supports. And ceiling() is the round up to nearest integer.

Comment: TSQL: Select  CASE WHEN Available > qtyPerPallet THEN Available / qtyPerPallet  ELSE 0 END as pallets, CASE WHEN Available > qtyPerPallet  THEN (Available % qtyPerPallet)  / qtyPerBox ELSE Available / qtyPerBox  END as boxes

Comment: @BartMcEndree That'll definitely work, but don't see why the CASE statements are necessary. Casting anything 0<=x<1 as integer will give 0 anyway.

Comment: @BartMcEndree, this seems to work for me. If we would want to allow the box column to round up, I was thinking to use CEILING in the case statement but didn't work. Would you have any suggestion?

 CASE WHEN Available >  qtyPerPallet THEN Available /  qtyPerPallet ELSE 0 END as pallets, 
  CASE 
   WHEN Available >  qtyPerPallet 
     THEN (Available /  qtyPerPallet) / qtyPerBox 
     ELSE ceiling(Available / qtyPerBox) 
  END as boxes

Comment: @VQB **please** edit the tags, remove "sql" and instead chose the database you actually need to query for. This is important so that the correct syntax is proposed, and it allows for your question to actually get answered

Comment: re the tag "sql" if you hover over it this is in part what it displays: *Questions should include code examples, table structure, sample data, and a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.) being used. If your question relates solely to a specific DBMS (uses specific extensions/features),* **use that DBMS's tag instead.** (emphasis added)

Comment: In SQL a `statement` is a declarative or procedural command used for operations such as data retrieval, manipulation, updating, deletion. An `expression` is one or more (values, operators and functions) that "evaluate to a single value" - this is what **case expressions** do, they "evaluate to a single value' and hence they are NOT statements.

Answer (score 1):

**Here's the example data in a "Readily Consumable format.**

Note that I added a couple of rows for the "Partial Box" tests.
Also note that this solution does NOT include "near full pallets.  I'd need to know what % of fullness is needed to qualify for that.

```
--=============================================================================
--      Create and populate a test table.
--      This is NOT a part of the solution but you should always post your
--      example data in such a "Readily Consumable" format to help those that
--      that would help you do so more quickly and with a tested answer.
--=============================================================================
   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TestTable;
GO
 CREATE TABLE #TestTable
        (
         Available  INT NOT NULL
        ,Qty_Pallet INT NOT NULL
        ,Qty_Box    INT NOT NULL
        )
;
 INSERT INTO #TestTable
        (Available, Qty_Pallet, Qty_Box)
 VALUES  (4800,2400,120)
        ,(1500,1000,100)
        ,(1550,1000,100) --Added
        ,(300 ,2000,100)
        ,(305 ,2000,100) --Added
;
```

**Here's one solution that includes "Partially Filled Boxes".**

```
--=============================================================================
--      Here's a solution that works and also accounts for "partial boxes".
--      It uses the simplicity of "Cascading CROSS APPLYs".
--=============================================================================
 SELECT  tt.Available
        ,tt.Qty_Pallet
        ,tt.Qty_Box
        ,pa.Pallets
        ,bx.Boxes
   FROM #TestTable tt
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES(tt.Available/Qty_Pallet))pa(Pallets)
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CEILING((tt.Available-pa.Pallets)*1.0/Qty_Box)))bx(Boxes)
;
```

**Here are the results:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using case expressions. Setup:

```
CREATE TABLE mydata (
      Available INT
    , qtyPerPallet INT
    , qtyPerBox INT
    );

INSERT INTO mydata (
       Available
    , qtyPerPallet
    , qtyPerBox
    )
VALUES   (4800,2400,120)
        ,(1500,1000,100)
        ,(1550,1000,100) --Added
        ,(300 ,2000,100)
        ,(305 ,2000,100) --Added
;
```

Query:

```
SELECT
      Available
    , qtyPerPallet
    , qtyPerBox
    , CASE 
        WHEN Available >= qtyPerPallet
            THEN Available / qtyPerPallet
            ELSE 0
        END AS pallets
    , CASE 
        WHEN Available % qtyPerPallet > 0
            THEN (Available % qtyPerPallet) / qtyPerBox
            ELSE 0
        END AS boxes
   , coalesce((Available % qtyPerPallet) % qtyPerBox,0) as remaining -- optional
FROM mydata;
```

| Available | qtyPerPallet | qtyPerBox | pallets | boxes | remaining |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4800 | 2400 | 120 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 1500 | 1000 | 100 | 1 | 5 | 0 |
| 1550 | 1000 | 100 | 1 | 5 | 50 |
| 300 | 2000 | 100 | 0 | 3 | 0 |
| 305 | 2000 | 100 | 0 | 3 | 5 |

see it working at this [SQL Server fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/96Bss4Oq)

Comment: Add a computed column for pallets and a computed column for boxes.  Pallets = available / quantityy per pallet.  Boxes = (available % quantity per pallet) / quantity per box

Comment: Mot sure what your comment requires as a reply - do you have a question?